# Kali Linux - Wireless Adapter: airodump-ng wlan0 - Error

Tags: kali-linux

I am doing a project on Kali Linux's airodump-ng command. Though, whenever I try to execute this command on a virtual machine (Virtual Box) with a Wireless USB adapter, I get this message as appose to a list of BSSID's:

> ioctl(SIOCSIWMODE) failed: Device or resource busy
>
> ARP linktype is set to 1 (Ethernet) - expected ARPHRD_IEEE80211,
>   ARPHRD_IEEE80211_FULL or ARPHRD_IEEE80211_PRISM instead. Make sure
>   RFMON is enabled: run 'airmon-ng start wlan0 <#>' Sysfs injection
>   support was not found either.

Is there a way to fix this? If so, please respod as soon as possible!

Answer (score 0):

1. Start monitor mode on your adapter with this:

`airmon-ng start wlan0`

2. In VBox's settings, make sure you are using your adapter.
3. Make sure you're not to far away from the network you are attempting to hack